# the question of the step in constructing an external automorphism of the group $S_6$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-homomorphism

[This](https://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2016/conf/4-3%20Karnik-Jagadeesan.pdf) presentation describes the construction of an outer automorphism of group $S_6$. To begin with, we construct a homomorphism from $S_5$ to $S_6$, using transitive action. It is further argued that $$|\ker f| \le\dfrac{|S_5|}{6} = 20$$
And the question is, where does this inequality come from?
Thanks for the help!

UPD: you can find detailed explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383676/s-6-contains-two-subgroups-that-are-isomorphic-to-s-5-but-are-not-conjugate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A homomorphism $f\colon S_5\to S_6$ is equivalent to an action of $S_5$ on the set $X:=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. If this action is transitive, then there is one orbit only, necessarily of size $|X|=6$, and thence (Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem):

$$6|\operatorname{Stab}(i)|=5!, \space\forall i\in X \tag 1$$

whence:

$$|\operatorname{Stab}(i)|=20, \space\forall i\in X \tag 2$$

Now, in general, for a $G$-action on a set $X$, the kernel of the equivalent homomorphism $f\colon G\to \operatorname{Sym}(X)$ is given by:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{ker} f &= \{g\in G\mid f_g=\iota_X\} \\
&= \{g\in G\mid f_g(x)=\iota_X(x), \forall x \in X\} \\
&= \{g\in G\mid g\cdot x=x, \forall x \in X\} \\
&= \{g\in G\mid g\in \operatorname{Stab}(x), \forall x \in X\} \\
&= \{g\in \operatorname{Stab}(x), \forall x \in X\} \\
&= \bigcap_{x\in X}\operatorname{Stab}(x) \\
\tag 3
\end{alignat}

Therefore, in our case, by $(3)$ and $(2)$:

$$|\ker f|=|\bigcap_{i\in X}\operatorname{Stab}(i)|\le 20 \tag 4$$

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If a group $G$ acts *transitively* on a set $X$ via $f\colon G\mapsto \operatorname{Sym}(X)$, then the image of $f$ has at least order $|X|$, hence the kernel is of index at least $|X|$.